# JRuby - How to start the garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jruby

I fired up my JRuby irb console and typed:

```
irb(main):037:0* GC.enable
(irb):37 warning: GC.enable does nothing on JRuby
=> true
irb(main):038:0> GC.start
=> nil
irb(main):039:0>
```

How can I manually enable or start the JVM garbage during a program?

I ask because I have a program which is needs to generate about 500 MBytes of test data and save it in MySQL. The program uses about 5 levels of nested loops, and it crashes with a JVM memory heap exception after generating about 100 MBytes of test data because there is no more heap memory. I would like to give let the garbage collector run after every run of the outer loop so that all the orphaned objects created in the inner loops can be cleaned up .

Comment: It's unlikely to help, because if the JVM runs out of memory, it would run the GC before giving up. You may need to make sure you're not holding references longer than they're needed and/or increase the heap size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exact answer to your question would be:

```
require 'java'

java_import 'java.lang.System'

# ...

System.gc()
```

though, bearing in mind even though the JVM usually *does* run the GC, it may or may not do it – very dependent on the JVM implementation.  It can also be quite a hit on performance.

A better answer is obviously to ensure that at the end of the nested loop, no reference is held on the test data you are generating, so that they can indeed be reclaimed by the GC later on. Example:

```
class Foo; end

sleep(5)

ary = []
100_000.times { 100_000.times{  ary << Foo.new }; puts 'Done'; ary = [] }
```

If you run this with `jruby -J-verbose:gc foo.rb`, you should see the GC regularly claiming the objects; this is also quite clear using JVisualVM (the `sleep` in the example is to give some time to connect to the Jruby process in JVisualVM).

Lastly you can increase heap memory by adding the following flag: `-J-Xmx256m`; see [the JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/PerformanceTuning) for more details.

**Edit:** Coincidentally, here is [a mindmap on GC tuning](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s167/sh/e994c854-2f8c-45fd-88bb-98e57f77a22e/61eb6b4e9b471d5ec44972f7b9ccf722/res/0847cb73-fb60-4e12-8ff0-4da62e02fc20/jvm-gc-tuning-20120525-093518.jpg.jpg) recently presented by Mario Camou at Madrid DevOps re-posted by Nick Sieger.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Sébastien. Your suggestions were very useful and helped us ask (and answer) more questions than we thought.

Comment: Thans for the answer.
one more example: https://gist.github.com/Shobhit1/f4ec5c9f1f47f3b8e70bb7d27a78fba9

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible because Gc will be run automatically by JVM. Make sure that you're creating objects only when it's required. Avoid creating class level objects and try to find out which of the objects is taking more memory and create it only when it's required.

Comment: That is not true. You have some sound advice, but it is possible to run GC manually.